# mdbreact table filter not working using React

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I am using datatable with help of `mdbreact` table from "https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/" here problem with search filter not working with table values. When I type string in search box following error throws [image] and app crashed.

```
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';

     const data = {
            columns: [
                {
                    label: 'Email',
                    field: 'emailid',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    width: 270
                },
                {
                    label: 'First Name',
                    field: 'namefirst',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    width: 270
                }
            ],
            rows: [
                 {"emailid": "xxx@gmail.com", "namefirst": "xxxxx"}]

        }
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
     <MDBDataTable                                                   
     striped
     hover
     data={data}
      />
    </div>

}
```

Here I assigned data static but in my application display dynamic values. On other pages search working fine same code I used but not working one page in my application.

Comment: Can some one help me out this problem?

Comment: the data looks correct, it might be something else outside of the code you show us. Can you provide the full code of the file?